# Use ethernet port for smb share transfers, but smb should still be accessible over wifi

Tags: networking, smb

I'm pretty new to Linux networking and I'm not sure how to fix a file transfer issue I have.

I have two Raspberry Pis. One is running Raspberry Pi OS and the other is running OSMC. Both are connected to a pretty dodgy Wi-Fi connection. I would like to periodically copy files from one Raspberry Pi to the other using smb, but because of the inconsistent WiFi connection, file transfers often fail.

To get around the inconsistent WiFi connection, I would like to connect a network cross cable between the two Raspberry Pis. Is there a way for me to keep the smb file share available over Wi-Fi, and when files transfer between the Raspberry Pi's, they make use of an ethernet cross cable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the wired and the WiFi interfaces were connected to the same router, you could bond them together (see https://fedoramagazine.org/bond-wifi-and-ethernet-for-easier-networking-mobility for an example; however I don't know if your respective OSs use NetworkManager). Perhaps your config also lends itself to bonding; if not, perhaps it could be made to work if you establish an adhoc WiFi connection between the two Pi's rather than going through an access point/router.